# iOS: Change contents of self (UIImage)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgcontextref

I have written some code in a UIImage category that takes a UIImage (self) and then redraws it using CGContextRef. Is there any way to rewrite the UIImage (self) while using CGBitmapContext? Currently, I have it returning the image that was created through the CGContextRef, but is it possible to rewrite the image itself within that method?

Comment: good question. The same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `UIImage` documentation:

> Image objects are immutable, so you cannot change their properties
>   after creation. ... Because image objects are immutable, they also do
>   not provide direct access to their underlying image data.

It is therefore not possible to change the image data of an `UIImage` after is has been created.